# Previous navigated screen appears when we move from main screen controls(button)

Tags: android

I have a main screen in my android application. There are 5 button in the main screen. When I click in first button it move to screen 1.Then I came back to my main screen and click button 2 then instead of navigating it to the Screen 2 it move earlier Screen 1.Similar thing is happening when I click any of the button in the main screen.

It was working perfectly earlier but now only this issue occurs. Did anyone experienced similar issue.

Comment: can you explain clearly about your issue?

Comment: Thanks for asking ..the issue got solved when i revert all the changes done in the android manifest file. I didn't done anything else in the android manifest file other than just creating a new activitity tag.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got solved when i revert all the changes done in the android manifest file. I didn't done anything else in the android manifest file other than just creating a new activity tag earlier.But when I revert back the android manifest file the issue got solved.I don't know its the right fix.